# How should I handle questions that could belong to physics.SE and other, more specialized, Stack Exchange websites?

Tags: discussion, questions, migration

First of all, I joined physics.SE only for the purpose of asking this question on Meta.

I asked a couple of questions regarding acoustic in sound.SE. For example [What are combs, nodes and how to calculate the nodes and comb frequencies at a given position?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/q/47023/25426) or to a lesser extent [How works perforated acoustic wood panels?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/q/47013/25426)

Those questions could belong to different SE sites. I originally chose sound.SE because I was interested in an answer from an audio engineer's point of view. However, those questions didn't get much attention.

Is there a procedure to raise the attention of the physics.SE contributors to questions asked on a different SE site? Or should I request the migration of the questions to physics.SE?

<sub>I'm aware that asking that on meta will *de facto* bring those questions to the attention of users active here. So in a sense, this question contains its own solution--which finally seems quite adequate for a "meta-question" ;)</sub>

Comment: The second question, "How works perforated acoustic wood panels?", seems to be quite broad and needs to be narrowed down a bit to better suite physics.SE.

Comment: Related: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7413/ https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6930/

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  @Johan I agree, the question was formatted in relatively casual terms for sound.SE. In that case, I wouldn't consider migrating the question as it is.

Comment: @tpg2114 Thanks for the links. Based on that, I wrote an answer you will find bellow. As I never used the SE chat before, I didn't think at all about that possible solution. So, let's try that first ;)

Comment: @tpg2114 Done. Posted in the chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53766950#53766950

Comment: Note that our main chat is [The H Bar](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar) (named after  a famous physical constant, $\hbar$, the reduced plank constant) and not the general chat.

Comment: Thanks, @Johan. I wasn't quite sure in which room I was supposed to post that--and obviously, I chose the wrong solution. But John Lennie was kind enough to move the post to the hBar.

Comment: FWIW, after following the different steps mentioned below, I finally reposted the question on pysics.SE :/ https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/536592/what-are-combs-nodes-and-how-to-calculate-the-nodes-and-comb-frequencies-at-a-g making it obvious it was a repost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In comments, @tgp2114 mentioned two related questions with possible solutions to deal with this kind of issue. I retained three basic ideas:

### 1. Post a link in chat

From https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6931/256325

> Choice (1), linking to the question in chat, is an old standby and usually works pretty well. These links often get starred so they draw attention even after they've rotated out of the main chat window.

### 2. Request migration

From https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6931/256325

> You posted a question but either realized it belongs elsewhere or got no satisfactory response, and there is another site where it is on topic. This seems to be your case. In that case it's probably best to migrate the question rather than duplicate it. Use a custom moderator flag on the question and request it be migrated to the other site. The moderators can then do this (or not, if they so choose).

## 3. Post another question tailored for the destination site

From https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6931/256325 too:

> You want a different take on the answer from a different community's perspective. Tailor the question appropriately, and note on both the old and new posts that there is a closely related question on another site.

---

So, I think the best strategy would be:

1. *First*, publish a link to the question in chat.
2. *If* this is still not satisfactory:
   2.1.  *If* the question is well suited for the destination site, request a migration.
   2.2. *Otherwise*, post a new question on the destination site, linking both questions with each other.

Comment: Yeah, this is basically the picture. With one important addition: whenever you cross-post, label it clearly and add links to every version pointing to every other version.

Comment: Yes, @Emilio. That's what I tried to say by "linking both questions with
 each other." But I agree, when translated to English, that statement wasn't as clear as it was in my mind. If you know a better wording, don't hesitate to make the change!

Comment: I would add that if you are cross-posting and the question has answers on the original SE site, you ought to explain why those answers are not satisfactory for you. You are essentially posting a Duplicate Question so the usual caveats apply as for such questions - eg you ought to consider whether an answer could be obtained by posting a follow-up question as a comment.

Comment: @Sammy If you looked, I did it. The user having answered admit he was wrong. But didn't bother fixing his answer. For the sake of "_no cross-post_", I suppose it's better to leave a wrong answer on sound.SE rather than requesting clarifications physics.SE? Sorry, terribly sorry for having dared to ask for help. I deleted my questions as you requested and I will stay in my ignorance. Thank you.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux You pointed out what was wrong with that user's answer; he agreed he'd made a simple error which was easy to correct. If you cared about the answer still being wrong you could have asked him to fix it. You didn't. The last two comments are his. The ball is in your court. There is no need for sarcasm.

Comment: There is no sarcasm. I just didn't understand some concepts of acoustics and I asked for clarifications regarding the meaning of "combs" "nodes" and how to calculate them. And despite what you say I didn't obtain that answer. Claiming the answer I got contained a "simple error [...] easy to correct" just confirm I shouldn't have asked for it in the first time. There is plenty of things I find easy you will find complicated. Accept that, once in a while, it might be the opposite.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux *Sorry, terribly sorry for having dared to ask for help.* That is sarcasm. If you want clarification of concepts the best way to get them is to ask in a comment the person who posted the answer. You have not done this. The user himself (not i) said that he had made a simple error about the distance in the calculation in response to your query. I did not suggest that you should not have asked the question on Sound Design SE.

Comment: @sammy: "_Sarcasm is when someone says something, but means something else."_ Stop pretending I said something but wanted to say something else. In case I wasn't clear: I asked here for clarifications after a doubtful answer on another site. This answer was given by a user to whom I asked for clarification already. He expressly requested I ask another question before answering. Now the follow up is no more clear to me than its initial answer. So I looked at more _definitive_ answer from _knowledgeable experts_ from another source. Unfortunately, I didn't obtain help, which I may understand...

Comment: ... I thought combining cross-sources wasn't that exceptional in the scientific domain. I also though SE was different from a mere forum.  But you come and say "it's your fault". And you claim I should have continued discussing again and again with the same source to finally obtain an answer. So my feelings _are_ that I shouldn't have asked on phyics.SE.

Comment: Anyway for what it worth, since I asked the question on physics.SE, I bought a couple of books on acoustics. And the answer I was looking for lies in a few well-written paragraphs. Much shorter than all the fuss caused by asking the question here. I now consider the case closed.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that your 2nd question [How works perforated acoustic wood panels](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/47013/how-works-perforated-acoustic-wood-panels) would be very suitable for Physics SE. It is a good fit here and it has not been answered to your satisfaction by anyone on Sound Design SE.

However your 1st question [What are combs, nodes and how to calculate the nodes and comb frequencies at a given position?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/47023/what-are-combs-nodes-and-how-to-calculate-the-nodes-and-comb-frequencies-at-a-g) does not seem to me to be suitable for this site because it is asking about the meaning of another person's statement.

This was a follow-up question to an answer you received to an earlier question [Why not pointing the loudspeaker toward the sky during open-field frequency response measurement?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/46988/why-not-pointing-the-loudspeaker-toward-the-sky-during-open-field-frequency-resp/46989#46989) The user who provided that answer, whose statement you are querying, also answered two other follow-up questions which you asked in the comments, and said he would try to answer a 3rd question if you posted it in the Stack. You subsequently posted the question and this user duly answered it. You have not up-voted or selected his answer but you appear to have run out of follow-up questions, which have all been answered.

**The person who makes a statement is usually the best person to explain what it means. He/she should be the first person you ask.** In fact he/she might be the only person who knows what the statement means.

There does not seem to me to be a good reason for cross-posting your 1st question on Physics SE.

So I would add to your strategy a preliminary step

### 0. If you are asking for clarification of someone else's post then make a comment under that Question or Answer.

Even if the post is old you can find out from the user's profile whether he/she is still active and likely to reply.